# Finding the latitude and Longitude inside Java Code

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am doing a project in which I have to find latitude longitude of all our clients,
So I have to do this manually by using Google Maps API.
Is there any other way  doing this through google directly inside my Java code?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Brian the link u have given is using javascript for geocoding.can a similar is provided by yahoo or other

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Geocoding web service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Please be mindful of the [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html)

Comment: thanks broady .... I need some guidance over this coz I've never used that...    Do u know about any tutorial related to this...

Comment: For Java, you'll want to use some sort of XML parser, and a way to send HTTP requests. Apache HttpClient may fit the bill.